# Why can't my CasperJS script login to Quora?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

This is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});



casper.start('http://www.quora.com', function()
        {
                this.click('input.submit_button');
                this.echo("page loaded");
                this.test.assertExists('form.inline_login_form', 'form is found');
            this.fill('form.inline_login_form',{email:'xxxxxx@gmail.com',password:'xxxx'},false);

        }
);

casper.then(function(){
        this.click('input.submit_button');

});

casper.then(function(){

        this.capture('google.png', {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width:0,
        height:0
    });
   this.echo("Page Title " + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

This is the image that the capture method produces:
[image]

Why doesn't it login?
The id and password are correct.

Comment: Try moving the capture into the `then` with the echo.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work.
This was the modified code I was using:
http://pastebin.com/gHKQt6vf

And I still get the same capture.
@hexid

Answer (score 2):

Try this, must work :

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
viewportSize: {
    width: 1080,
    height: 768
}
}); 
var email = "xxx@abc.com"; 
var pass = "********";



casper.start('http://www.quora.com', function()
    {
            this.click('input.submit_button');
            this.echo("page loaded");
            this.test.assertExists('form.inline_login_form', 'form is found');
        this.fill('form#__w2_b3oUn76_login_form',{email:'email',password:'pass'},true);

    });

casper.waitForSelector("form[name=search_form] input[name='search_input']",
function(){
    this.capture('google.png');
   this.echo("Page Title " + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add some wait statements between request.  there may be some ajax you're not allowing enough time to be fired.  you also will want to add a user agent.  Sometimes different versions of the webpage are delivered if they sniffed out your user agent.